# Does the rest of them or Do the rest of them?

Tags: grammatical-number, do

In this situation, where "The Committee" is a group of roughly 9 men, which sentence would be correct? (One man from the group did something)

Does the rest of The Committee know of this?
Do the rest of the Committee know of this?

Comment: In "do/does the [X] know this", do/does should agree numerically with X. I'd consider "rest of the committee" non-count here: "**does** the ...". But if X was just "rest", it would normally be treated as a count noun, so assuming more than 1 member in *the rest*: "**do** the rest know this".

Comment: This question is still unanswered. Can anyone provide an answer? Lawrence, "do the rest know this" is different from "Do the rest of The Committee know this?" And I would put does in both honestly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Comment: Possible duplicate of and answered at [subject-verb agreement with the head word "the rest"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348484/subject-verb-agreement-with-the-head-word-the-rest): see @BillJ's response (in a comment) about the behaviour of quantificational nouns. There is also a notional consideration here (I'd use 'The committee are arguing heatedly among themselves', say).

Answer (score -1):

This is s British English/American English issue, I should think:

http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/

Comment: Please summarize the argument. If the linked document is moved, your link will point nowhere and this answer will be far less useful.

Answer (score -1):

Does the rest of The Committee know this?

The Committy is subject of the sentence; the word *rest* is the adverb since it tells us more about the committee: there are more members in it.

The verb conjugation follows the *subject*, here being The Committee, which is a singular third person (one can refer to the committee it as "it")

The third person singular of the verb "to be" conjugates as: DOES.
Hence, the right way of writing here is: **Does** the rest of The Committee know this?

I hope this helps you out?